# AnjularJs integration with Spring boot

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, hibernate

I need to call `index()` method in java class. But I tried this way it is not working.

It is going up to `console.log('coming here....');` in `controller.js`, after that http path is not recognizing.

```
@RestController
public class DatumBoxShedule {

    @Autowired
    private DatumService datumService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadIndex", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,  method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() throws IOException {

    }
}
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('datumBoxShedule', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.newTodo = {};

    $scope.loadIndex = function(){
         console.log('coming here....');
        $http.get('loadIndex')
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.todos = data;
         })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              alert('Error loading DatumBoxShedule');
        });
    };

    $scope.loadIndex();
});
```

Comment: try to inspect the status code, it's likely 404 and that means you need to provide absolute path: `$http.get('/loadIndex')...`. You can access the Rest API endpoint directly from browser, or use a browser extension like Postman to inspect the request/response.

Comment: I tried $http.get('/loadIndex') but still same error is coming.

Comment: Which the base context of backend REST service? Usually you will have something like `http://host:port/*myApp*/loadIndex`

Comment: my context is http://localhost:8080/loadIndex

Answer (score 0):

Is the Angular project part of the Spring project?

Are other mappings working (in other words: is the REST-Service running)?
If not: do you have an embedded container like Tomcat in your depenedencies?

For example, you could add the dependency for Tomcat to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message from the debugging console of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

I figureout ,issue is not in the anujularjs.Issue is in the spring.

my componantscan is not working

package main.java.datumbox;

@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan({"main.java.datumbox.service.impl","main.java.datumbox.controller","main.java.datumbox.service"})
public class Application{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);

}
```

}

package main.java.datumbox.service.impl;

public class DatumServiceImpl{

```
@Autowired(required = true)
DatumDataRepository datumDataRepository;
```

}

package main.java.datumbox.controller;

@RestController
public class DatumBoxController {

```
@Autowired
private DatumService datumService;

@Autowired
private DatumServiceImpl datumServiceImpl;


@RequestMapping( value = "/loadIndex" , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() throws IOException {

}
```

}

package main.java.datumbox.service;

@Service
public class DatumService{

```
@Autowired
HitApiService hitApiService;
```

}

error is coming..

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field datumServiceImpl in main.java.datumbox.controller.DatumBoxController required a bean of type 'main.java.datumbox.service.impl.DatumServiceImpl' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'main.java.datumbox.service.impl.DatumServiceImpl' in your configuration.